# sqs queues are not receiving messages from sns sometimes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a topic that broadcasts events when user does an action. There are 2 queues which are subscribed to this topic. But they are receiving messages only once in 3-4 times. Sometimes messages is not received by both topics. Sometimes it is received by only one and sometimes by both. It started happening 4 weeks back.

Solutions I have tried so far:

- I rechecked the permissions and policies. Everything seems right. (If this is the issue then i should not be receiving messages at all)
- I checked if those same queues are running somewhere which are receiving and deleting messages from queue before production server receives them
- I deleted and recreated the topics, queues and subscriptions
- I checked aws forums, stack overflow everywhere

Delivery Retry Policy for the topic:

```
{
  "http": {
    "defaultHealthyRetryPolicy": {
      "numRetries": 3,
      "numNoDelayRetries": 0,
      "minDelayTarget": 20,
      "maxDelayTarget": 20,
      "numMinDelayRetries": 0,
      "numMaxDelayRetries": 0,
      "backoffFunction": "linear"
    },
    "disableSubscriptionOverrides": false
  }
}
```

Access Policy for topic:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
        "SNS:AddPermission",
        "SNS:RemovePermission",
        "SNS:DeleteTopic",
        "SNS:Subscribe",
        "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
        "SNS:Publish",
        "SNS:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:********:*****_******_*******",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "AWS:SourceOwner": "*********"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Access Policy for a queue:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__owner_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::********:root"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:********:***********_*******"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "topic-subscription-arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:********:*****_******_*******",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:SendMessage",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:********:***********_*******",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:********:*****_******_*******"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Configuration of a queue:
[image]

Please let me know if any more information is needed. I am going to get aws premium support to find the problem. I wanted to post here once before that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you checked `NumberOfNotificationsFailed` metric if it shows failed messages? Have you setup [logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-topic-attributes.html) for sns to log failed messages?

Comment: ```NumberOfNotificationsFailed``` is 0 for the topic. It shows that all notifications were delivered.

Comment: So what are your SQS queue doing with those messages? How do you know they are not delivered?

Comment: My consumers in the code are not receiving the messages. I added logs everywhere. Sometimes those get logged and data gets updated. sometimes they don't. We have the exact same architecture in other regions with other environments. There we are receiving all the messages. We are facing this issue only in production with this particular topic and queues.

Comment: If you have the same architecture working in different region, but not the current, maybe its some regional issue. As you said, maybe aws support can help.

Comment: Yes. that is conclusion I came to after working on this issue for past 3 days. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @RAM If you solved this issue would you mind sharing your solution?

Comment: @AaronM There was an abandoned server which was also receiving the messages. That is why existing server is only receiving sometimes. Has nothing to do with configurations.